# Why not broadcast confirmation once the receiver has confirmed the block successfully

Tags: nodeos, bft-dpos

Now in the main net, when a transaction is packaged, it means that the current node confirms it, and it needs at least 2/3 of the 21 super nodes to confirm. In addition, two rounds of confirmation are required.

Therefore, the difference between the current block height and the irreversible block height, up to a maximum of 336( 2 * (2/3) * 21 * 12 = 336 ).

Why not broadcast confirmation to make a block become irreversible faster?

Comment: I know this is by the current design. But, why did you design like that? I remember that the white paper said a block would become irreversible about 1.5 seconds.

Comment: bft_irreversible_blocknum will be changed if the function "push_confirmation" is called. However, I can't find the function is called.

Comment: the implementation to communicate commitments faster is a work in progress